# The recovery server could not be contacted

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, high-sierra, error

I factory reset my Mac and followed the steps until I saw this:

I tried running the command:

`npdate -u time.apple.com`

and

`date mmddhhmmyy`

[image]

It still does not work. How do I resolve the issue?

I think that the problem is not about the date. I tried to check the logs.

This is what showed up.

[image]

What do you think is the problem? Thank you for the time I just really need this.